# Hilla not starting Vite - what am I missing?

Tags: spring-boot, hilla

I have created a hilla app using this:

```
npx @vaadin/cli init --hilla --auth hilla-with-auth
```

Works fine!
Now I am trying to add that to an existing spring boot application, but I am having issues with Vite not starting as it should. No exception. No help in the debug output.

I have added:

- relevant files in the root (package.json, vite.config.ts, etc.)
- vaadin-featureflags.properties in resources folder
- hilla dependencies in pom.xml as well as the build plugin
- hill annotations to my application class (@Theme, @PWA) and made it `extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator`

But even if everything seems to be initialized correctly, Vite does not start. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

This is the most relevant output log:

```
2022-06-07 08:04:54.046 DEBUG 4947 --- [restartedMain] c.v.f.s.f.s.FullDependenciesScanner      : 
     List of npm dependencies found in the project:
      - @hilla/form 1.0.1 dev.hilla.EndpointController
      ....
    2022-06-07 08:04:54.057 DEBUG 4947 --- [restartedMain] c.v.f.s.f.TaskGeneratePackageJson        : writing file /Users/michael/Development/Previsto/previsto-server/target/flow-frontend/package.json.
    2022-06-07 08:05:02.102  INFO 4947 --- [restartedMain] o.a.container.JSR356AsyncSupport         : JSR 356 Mapping path /vaadinServlet
    2022-06-07 08:05:02.176  INFO 4947 --- [restartedMain] c.v.f.s.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration   : 
    Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
    When deploying application for production, remember to disable debug features. See more from https://vaadin.com/docs/
    
    The following EXPERIMENTAL features are enabled:
    - Use Vite for faster front-end builds
    
    
    2022-06-07 08:05:02.207 DEBUG 4947 --- [restartedMain] c.v.f.s.c.PushRequestHandler             : Using pre-initialized Atmosphere for servlet springServlet
    2022-06-07 08:05:02.210 DEBUG 4947 --- [restartedMain] c.v.flow.server.VaadinServletService     : Using 'com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.IndexHtmlRequestHandler' in client mode bootstrapping
    2022-06-07 08:05:02.212 DEBUG 4947 --- [restartedMain] com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService     : The application has the following routes: 
    2022-06-07 08:05:02.956  INFO 4947 --- [restartedMain] c.v.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools   : Project node version 16.10.0 is older than 16.14.0. Using node from /Users/michael/.vaadin.
    2022-06-07 08:05:03.404 DEBUG 4947 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-1] c.v.f.s.s.VaadinDefaultRequestCache      : Saving request to /
    2022-06-07 08:05:03.471 DEBUG 4947 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Requesting resource from Vite http://localhost:0/login
    2022-06-07 08:05:03.486 ERROR 4947 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[springServlet]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [springServlet] threw exception
    
    java.net.ConnectException: Can't assign requested address (connect failed)
        at ...
```

Comment: There was a bug in earlier versions that prevented showing the error from the dev server startup and instead just tried to connect to port 0 like in your output. Try with 1.1.0 and see if it shows the actual problem

Comment: I tried with 1.0.11 (latest in central it seems). And it actually gave me more details.

Issue was that another package had a reference to commons-io 2.4, but it needs to be commons-io 2.7.

Specifically this line refers to a method that is not available in commons-io 2.4:
https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/master/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/server/frontend/NodeUpdater.java#L589